After migration, constant error messages but most things work?
Managed a mostly successful migration of our WordPress site to a new domain, along with CiviCRM — had to manually move its tables & update the pw, and then set up cron on the new server. Everything seems to be working fine.
But I get constant error messages, which range from "You do not have permission to access this page" (the one I am nevertheless accessing) to "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again" (also not true).
Still, because it's mostly working (and we have things to do), I was able to schedule and send a mailout today … but I'm unable to see the report: "Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. You do not have permission to access this page."
Any ideas? Something in the db not right? The access controls and permissions and everything appear to be correct, I've flushed the tables so many times.

Quick update: I've narrowed it down (I think) to the "Mailing Summary" dashlet — my (admin) users apparently no longer have access to mailing info (which is why I consistently get an error when trying to run mailer reports). But everything else seems to be working.
Help? Where else can I look?

[facepalm]
I finally realized that I needed to work back through the initial configuration and — way more importantly — re-enable the CiviMail component. I'm not sure how any part of it was working, but, having done that, everything is fine.
